# Fullscreen GIF animation in Cocos2D

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone, gif

I have an animation (images serie) to do on the entire screen of the iPhone (retina and no retina) 
Normally I do that with zwoptex using a similary technique to this http://gamedev.sugartin.info/2012/05/09/69/

But this time the size of images doesn't allow that.

I have also a 5sec-length video of the serie.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any kind of images, that you want to display, must be placed in memory first of all. so, you cannot play animation, if you have too many frames to be loaded to memory. if you want to play such big animation, you can try to create video file and play it over your openGL view